# make gem specific version default for all environment [Ruby on Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

when I ran `gem list` I get two different versions of gems I've installed:

```
bigdecimal (1.2.7, default: 1.2.6)
io-console (0.4.5, default: 0.4.3)
json (1.8.3, default: 1.8.1)
lunchy (0.10.4)
psych (2.0.17, default: 2.0.8)
rake (11.1.2, default: 10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.2, default: 4.2.0)
```

How can I set rake 11.1.2 as default? this is not for a particular projet but my gems in general, so there's no Gemfile.

Thanks in advance.